# Jackson: timezone differs of default system timezone?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

I've this code:

```
Date timestamp = new Date();

LOG.info("timestamp timezone: " + Integer.toString(timestamp.getTimezoneOffset()));

MetadataFields metadataFields;
metadataFields = this.objectMapper.readValue(this.value, MetadataFields.class);

LOG.info("fields timezone: " + Integer.toString(metadataFields.getDataSolicitudGSIT().getTimezoneOffset()));
```

I'm getting this logs:

```
timestamp timezone: -60
fields timezone: -120
```

It's seems `ObjectMapper` is using a different timezone of default system.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you will check the source code for [DateTimeDeserializer](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/joda/deser/DateTimeDeserializer.java) shows it uses the timezone from DeserializationContext which is provided by `ObjectMapper` during deserialization. If you look at [ObjectMapper](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html).

```
public ObjectMapper setTimeZone(TimeZone tz)
```

So this method to configure your `ObjectMapper` and set the timezone to the correct one.

You can set this explicitly here:

```
protected final static BaseSettings DEFAULT_BASE = new BaseSettings(
    ...
    TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"),
    ...
```

So the best choice is set it by yourself using `ObjectMapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone tz)`.